# UIButton in custom UIView doesn't register Tap event?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton

I have created a custom view SearchOptionsView which contains a button. When I use addTarget on the button, nothing happens. I wonder what I could be doing wrong? Please try the code below:

```
import UIKit

protocol SearchOptionsViewDelegate {
func polygonSelected(_ sender: UIButton)
}

class SearchOptionsView : UIView {

var delegate: SearchOptionsViewDelegate?

let container: UIView = {
    let container = UIView()
    container.backgroundColor = .white
    container.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    container.layer.masksToBounds=true
    container.alpha = 0
    container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
    return container
}()

let topSectionWrapper: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
    return view
}()

let headerLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Please select what you want to do next"
    label.font=UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 22)
    label.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
    return label
}()

let infoLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text="If you want to draw a polygon in a certain area, select the first choice. To draw a circle around a center point, select the second one. For more filters, select the third option."
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.font=UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
    label.textColor=UIColor.darkGray
    label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
    return label
}()

let bottomSectionWrapper: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(r:228,g:238,b:242)
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
    view.clipsToBounds = true
    return view
}()

let polygonButton : UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(r:150,g:213,b:76)
    button.setTitle("POLYGON", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font=UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    button.layer.masksToBounds = true
    return button
}()

let radiusButton : UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(r:150,g:213,b:76)
    button.setTitle("RADIUS", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font=UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    button.layer.masksToBounds = true
    return button
}()

let filtersButton : UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(r:150,g:213,b:76)
    button.setTitle("FILTERS", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font=UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    button.layer.masksToBounds = true
    return button
}()

func setupViews(){

    self.frame=bounds
    self.addSubview(container)

    self.container.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive=true
    self.container.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive=true
    self.container.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive=true
    self.container.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive=true

    self.container.addSubview(topSectionWrapper)

    topSectionWrapper.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.leadingAnchor).isActive=true
    topSectionWrapper.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.trailingAnchor).isActive=true
    topSectionWrapper.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.topAnchor).isActive=true
    topSectionWrapper.heightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: container.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1/2).isActive=true

    topSectionWrapper.addSubview(headerLabel)

    headerLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topSectionWrapper.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive=true
    headerLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topSectionWrapper.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive=true
    headerLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topSectionWrapper.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive=true
    //headerLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive=true

    topSectionWrapper.addSubview(infoLabel)

    infoLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerLabel.leadingAnchor).isActive=true
    infoLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerLabel.trailingAnchor).isActive=true
    infoLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive=true

    self.container.addSubview(bottomSectionWrapper)

    bottomSectionWrapper.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.leadingAnchor).isActive=true
    bottomSectionWrapper.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.trailingAnchor).isActive=true
    bottomSectionWrapper.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.bottomAnchor).isActive=true
    bottomSectionWrapper.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1/2).isActive=true

    bottomSectionWrapper.addSubview(polygonButton)
    bottomSectionWrapper.addSubview(radiusButton)
    bottomSectionWrapper.addSubview(filtersButton)

    let heightForButtons : CGFloat = ((self.bounds.height / 2) / 3 ) - 60
    print("button height is \(heightForButtons)")

    polygonButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomSectionWrapper.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive=true
    polygonButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomSectionWrapper.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive=true
    polygonButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomSectionWrapper.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive=true
    polygonButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive=true

    radiusButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomSectionWrapper.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive=true
    radiusButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomSectionWrapper.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive=true
    radiusButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: polygonButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive=true
    radiusButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive=true

    filtersButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomSectionWrapper.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive=true
    filtersButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomSectionWrapper.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive=true
    filtersButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: radiusButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive=true
    filtersButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive=true

    polygonButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SearchOptionsView.polygonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}

func showSearchOptions(){
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        print("showing dialog")
        self.container.alpha = 0.90
    }
}

func hideSearchOptions(){
    self.container.alpha = 0
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame:frame)
    setupViews()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    let heightForButtons : CGFloat = ((self.bounds.height / 2) / 3 ) - 60
    print("layoutSubviews() :: button height is \(heightForButtons)")
}

@objc func polygonTapped(_ sender:UIButton){
    print("polygon button tapped")
    delegate?.polygonSelected(sender)
}
}
```

I have used this Control from a ViewController where I set the delegate in the viewDidLoad() function. There is no error but no matter what I do, the button tap is never called. Can anyone help?

Inside the Controller I define the custom control like so:

```
let searchOptionsDialog : SearchOptionsView = {
    let options = SearchOptionsView(frame: .zero)
    options.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
    options.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    options.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    return options
}()
```

Does setting the frame to .zero has any issue with the view?

Here's the controller code where I have created the View programatically. I have tried everything I could but something is stopping the action trigger.

```
import UIKit
import SideMenu
import GoogleMaps

class SearchController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, SearchOptionsViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate 
{
    func polygonSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.activatePolygon()
    }


let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
lazy var mapView = GMSMapView()
var polygon: GMSPolygon?
var circle: GMSCircle?
lazy var polygonPoints = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()
lazy var markers = [GMSMarker]()

var activeSearchMode = SearchMode.none

let mainContainer: UIView = {
    let container = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    container.backgroundColor = .red
    container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    container.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    return container
}()

let searchOptionsDialog : SearchOptionsView = {
    let options = SearchOptionsView(frame: .zero)
    options.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
    options.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    return options
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(r:0,g:157,b:220)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(r:0,g:157,b:220)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor =  UIColor.clear
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]

    self.navigationItem.title = "Search"
    let hamburgerIcon = UIImage(named: "menu-three-lines")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    let hamburgerButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: hamburgerIcon, style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(rightBarButtonTapped))
    //self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [hamburgerButton, negativeSpacerButton]
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = hamburgerButton

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
    let menuRightNavController  = UISideMenuNavigationController(rootViewController: MenuController())
    SideMenuManager.default.menuRightNavigationController = menuRightNavController
    SideMenuManager.default.menuWidth = max(round(min(self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height) * 0.80), 240)
    SideMenuManager.default.menuAddPanGestureToPresent(toView: self.navigationController!.navigationBar)
    SideMenuManager.default.menuAddScreenEdgePanGesturesToPresent(toView: self.navigationController!.view)

    self.polygon = nil
    self.circle = nil

    searchOptionsDialog.delegate = self

    setupViews()

}

@objc func activatePolygon(){
    self.activeSearchMode = SearchMode.polygon
    self.searchOptionsDialog.hideSearchOptions()
    print("polygon is set")
}

@objc func activateRadius(){
    self.activeSearchMode = SearchMode.radius
    // self.searchOptionsDialog.hideSearchOptions()
}

@objc func activateFilters(){
    self.activeSearchMode = SearchMode.filters
    // self.searchOptionsDialog.hideSearchOptions()
}

func setupViews(){
    mainContainer.frame = view.frame
    view.addSubview(mainContainer)
    addMapView()
    mainContainer.addSubview(searchOptionsDialog)

    //mainContainer.bringSubview(toFront: optionsDialogContainer)
    addConstraints()
}

func addMapView(){
    let camera  = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6.0)
    mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: mainContainer.frame, camera: camera)
    mapView.delegate = self
    mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
    mapView.settings.zoomGestures = true
    mainContainer.addSubview(mapView)
}

func addConstraints(){
    searchOptionsDialog.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive=true
    searchOptionsDialog.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive=true
    searchOptionsDialog.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor, constant: -100 ).isActive=true
    searchOptionsDialog.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 350).isActive=true
    //searchOptionsDialog.clipsToBounds = true
}

@objc func rightBarButtonTapped(){
    print("Open SideMenu ..")
    self.present(SideMenuManager.default.menuRightNavigationController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func mapViewDidFinishTileRendering(_ mapView: GMSMapView) {
    self.mainContainer.bringSubview(toFront: searchOptionsDialog)
    self.searchOptionsDialog.showSearchOptions()

    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let userLocation  = locations.last
    let camera  = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: userLocation!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation!.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 13.0)
    mapView.animate(to: camera)
    mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    print("locations = \(userLocation!.coordinate.latitude) \(userLocation!.coordinate.longitude)")
}

func redrawPolygon(){
    if self.markers.count < 3 {
        return
    }
}

func redrawCircle(marker: GMSMarker){

}

func redrawShape(marker: GMSMarker){
    if activeSearchMode == SearchMode.polygon {
        redrawPolygon()
    } else if activeSearchMode == SearchMode.radius {
        redrawCircle(marker: marker)
    }
}

// delegate functions
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    print("map tapped ")
    if activeSearchMode == SearchMode.polygon {
        polygonPoints.append(coordinate)
        let m = GMSMarker(position: coordinate)
        m.isDraggable = true
        m.map = self.mapView
        markers.append(m)
        if markers.count >= 3 {
            polygon?.map = nil
            let path = GMSMutablePath()
            for point in polygonPoints {
                path.add(point)
            }
            polygon = GMSPolygon(path: path)
        }
    }
}

// when someone taps the marker
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
    switch self.activeSearchMode {
    case SearchMode.polygon:
        print("polygon case active")
        if markers.count == 3 {
            markers.forEach { $0.map=nil }
            markers.removeAll()
            polygonPoints.removeAll()
        } else {
            if let index = markers.index(of: marker) {
                marker.map=nil
                markers.remove(at: index)
            }
            // remove the marker tappped from the polygon
            for (index,polygon) in polygonPoints.enumerated() {
                if marker.position.latitude == polygon.latitude
                    && marker.position.longitude == polygon.longitude {
                    polygonPoints.remove(at: index)
                }
            }
        }
    case SearchMode.radius:
        print("Radius case active")
    default:
        print("query filter case active")
    }

    return true
}

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didBeginDragging marker: GMSMarker) {
    redrawShape(marker: marker)
}

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didEndDragging marker: GMSMarker) {
    redrawShape(marker: marker)
}

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didDrag marker: GMSMarker) {
    redrawShape(marker: marker)
}

func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    if (touch.view?.isDescendant(of: self.searchOptionsDialog))!{
        return false
    }
    return true
}

enum SearchMode {
    case polygon, radius, filters, none
}
}
```

I have used a library called SideMenu for this app. I thought maybe I could override the gesture which I did but even that didn't work. Totally in a fix.

Comment: I'd start by using Xcode's view debugger (the button looks like two rectangles turned 90° and stacked a bit to the right of the pause button) to make sure no other views are over top of the button (stacking order of the views may have not be what you think).

Comment: @theMikeSwan I am not sure how to use the tool (sorry I am very new to ios programming and xcode) but I did check the Debug View Hierarchy button like you said and I don't think anything is overlaying the buttons except its own labels. I moved the range control to the right and the button seems to go the last in the view. Am I making any sense here?